# RedisClientManager, An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack.redis

I m using RedisClientManager and I m gettin **An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll** error while trying to set an object

```
client.Set<ApplicationUser>(user.Id, user);
```

And User :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int BirthPlace { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int AvatarId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CodeSendDate { get; set; }
    public string ActivationCode { get; set; }
    public string PasswordResetToken { get; set; }
    public string FacebookAvatar { get; set; }
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }
    public bool UseFacebookAvatar { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
}
```

The error occure while serialize ApplicationUser, i try to add `[JsonIgnore]` on ICollection beacuse of nested loop,(Coupon contains user )
I can not find whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it works for me. 
ApplicationUser object has Coupon and Coupon has ApplicationUser (many to many)
so the serialize going infinite loop.

I add `[IgnoreDataMember]`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int BirthPlace { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int AvatarId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }        
    public DateTime RegisterationDate { get; set; }        
    public DateTime CodeSendDate { get; set; }
    public string ActivationCode { get; set; }
    public string PasswordResetToken { get; set; }
    public string FacebookAvatar { get; set; }
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }
    public bool UseFacebookAvatar { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }        

    public virtual Avatar Avatar { get; set; }


    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
}
```

Now i can ignore Coupon property so Servis.Stack redisClientManager can seriazlie the object.